# onblur event not working with google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, onblur

I am trying to use onblur event to close a window. Its working fine in IE, Firefox and safari, but the event does not trigger in chrome. is that a  bug in chrome or a mistake from me

Comment: are you trying to use window.onBlur?  Could you provide a code example - it is easier for everyone to help you then.

Comment: You really should add a code example to your question

Answer (score 9):

I realize this was over a year ago, but it showed up for me in Google while trying to solve this same issue.

It seems Chrome does not consider some elements, like body and anchors, to be "focusable". According to the following page, you can make any element focusable (thereby activating the blur event) by setting the *tabindex* attribute: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/blurfocus.html

Like so:

```
<a href="#" tabindex="0" onblur="alert('blur')"> blur me </a>
```

Comment: A good solution but doesn't seem to work for `button` elements.

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this issue...

onBlur (with a capital "B") doesn't work, but onblur (lowercase "b") does.  Go figure!  ;-/

Comment: There's nothing in the language that suggests it's anything other than all lowercase.

Comment: Well, yes it is! Everything is camelcase except this!

Answer (score 0):

Chrome accepts OnBlur event. what i have experience is... on check or uncheck of checkbox, chrome do not focus on it.

Add attribute

```
onclick="this.focus()" onblur="yourMethod()"/>
```

you will see it work fine then.