# Event to capture every render of MagicSuggest box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, magicsuggest

I am applying CSS to the 'selected item' boxes of a [Magicsuggest](http://nicolasbize.github.io/magicsuggest/) box, each time the 'selectionchange' event is fired. However, it appears these boxes are re-rendered every time the input div loses or gains focus.

With Firefox, I have caught these by reapplying my CSS on the blur and focus events. (Which works, albeit very resource intensive for what I'm trying to do.) In Chrome however, the blur event is never fired (Due to [something along these lines, I think.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407679/onblur-event-not-working-with-google-chrome)). **Is anyone able to work out a way I can capture every re-render of the box with one event, or an alternative solution?**

**Update 31/8:** It now seems that Firefox and Chrome behaviour is the same, my css effects are lost on blur.

More info:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZyA7B/16/

The code I'm attempting to capture the events with

```
$(ms).on('blur focus', function(event){
    console.log('fired');
        var selDivs = $(event.target._valueContainer[0].parentNode).children('div');            //Get all the divs in the selction 
        $.each(selDivs,function(index,value){                                $(value).css('background','blue');         
        });
    });
```

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle that reproduces the issue? I'll look into it. Thanks

Comment: @jothetomato - I've long since moved on to using a different plugin for this functionality, due to this issue, and a few others I can't remember. I'll hunt through my repository at some point however, and see if I can find the relevant version, for posterity. Cheers!

Comment: That would be very helpful thanks

Comment: Hi @jothetomato. I've botched something together out of old code, but it comes with the disclaimer I haven't put any effort into hunting down the problem with the new version! As I said, I've long since moved on to something different, so it's no longer of any use to me, but if you want it as a bug-hunt for your tool, then absolutely! From memory, my issue was that my bg coloring was lost onblur of the MS. However Firefox and Chrome behaviour seems the same on this JSFiddle, so I don't think it's exactly as I have before, apologies! Cheers¬